# Unable to start payara server

Tags: java, server, payara

I am not able to restart the server.

Beginning i killed all process and restarted the server. I got the successful message, but the application was not working. Again i stopped and started the service. Now the system shows like there is another process is running on the server as below.

```
[pdpadmin@saclx065 bin]$ killall -9 java
[pdpadmin@saclx065 bin]$ ./asadmin start-domain pdpws
Waiting for pdpws to start ............................................
Successfully started the domain : pdpws
domain  Location: /pdp/payara41/glassfish/domains/pdpws
Log File: /pdp/payara41/glassfish/domains/pdpws/logs/server.log
Admin Port: 9048
Command start-domain executed successfully.
[pdpadmin@saclx065 bin]$ ./asadmin start-domain pdp
Waiting for pdp to start .......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
serverNoStart
Command start-domain failed.
[pdpadmin@saclx065 bin]$ ./asadmin start-domain pdpws
There is a process already using the admin port 9048 -- it could be another instance of Payara Server or Payara Micro.
Command start-domain failed.
```

Can you help me to check this issue?

Comment: if using linux type "netstat -plten | grep 9048" to get the process id and kill it to free the port

Comment: this is unix server. shall i use the same command to kill?

Comment: i haven't used the payara i have just given the solution to free the port ..

Comment: thanks Ankur. For unix, the command should be like ps -aef|grep 9048. I have tried this and the execution is successful(as per the message shown in the server log). but the server is not running.

Comment: Is this a programming question? Perhaps you could get more help on ServerFault.

Comment: yeah Steve. I am not able to start the server.

Answer (score 2):

You have started two different domains `pdpws` and `pdp`. If both domains are configured to use port 9048 as the admin port, it's not possible to run them on the same server. You have to choose a different port.

However you should not kill your domain with the `killall` command but instead shut it down with `./asadmin stop-domain pdpws` and `./asadmin stop-domain pdp`. It would be even better to create a service-script.

A service-script for payara on a unix-system with systemctl could be done as following: Create a file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/payara.service` with this content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Payara Server
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

ExecStart=/opt/payara41/glassfish/bin/asadmin start-domain pdpws
ExecStop=/opt/payara41/glassfish/bin/asadmin stop-domain pdpws

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Than you can call:

```
systemctl start payara
systemctl stop payara
```

Comment: I have separate port for pdp->4848 and pdpws->9048. Shall i proceed with this solution then?

Comment: Using `killall` to stop an application server is never a good option, so yes you should use `stop-domain`. If it is possible to restart the whole server, that should be an easy way to free up your ports for now. Then always use `stop-domain` or `restart-domain` and you should be fine. The service script is just some bonus you can do.

Comment: Thanks Dennis. Regarding payara.service file... should i give ExceStart and ExecStop as the same you have given? Why i am asking is i have two different domains that are mounted on two different port. if i give only for pdpws, how can i use the same for pdp?

Comment: I would advice you to create two different service-scripts for both domains. So you can call one `payara_pdpws.service` and the other `payara_pdp.service` for example. Than you can use `systemctl start payara_pdpws`.
As an alternative you could create a bash-script executing `start-domain pdpws` and then `start-domain pdp` and call this script from your service-script.

Comment: Thanks Dennis!  `Tpye=forking` is essential otherwise the server will start and immediately stop.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by reloading the application. What is the difference between redeploying, restarting and reloading applications in server?

Answer (score 0):

Here are Production ready start, stop, cleaning bash tool for payara. Please note your payara version where exist.. and add this bash file -> usr/bin on Centos.... and give execution permission (chmod a+x /usr/bin/file_name) and ownership(chown your_user:your_user /usr/bin/file_name) for default user

```
#!/bin/bash 

BLACK=$(tput setaf 0)
RED=$(tput setaf 1)
GREEN=$(tput setaf 2)
YELLOW=$(tput setaf 3)
LIME_YELLOW=$(tput setaf 190)
POWDER_BLUE=$(tput setaf 153)
BLUE=$(tput setaf 4)
MAGENTA=$(tput setaf 5)
CYAN=$(tput setaf 6)
WHITE=$(tput setaf 7)
BRIGHT=$(tput bold)
NORMAL=$(tput sgr0)
BLINK=$(tput blink)
REVERSE=$(tput smso)
UNDERLINE=$(tput smul)





printf "${GREEN}\n\n\n       welcome to TEKILA App commander \n\n"
printf "${GREEN}before start please switch java version with command if requires\n\n" 
printf "${RED}  alternatives --config java \n\n"

printf "\n${YELLOW}     Payara 4.1 (required environment java 1.8)  \n\n"
printf "${MAGENTA} p1     start\n"
printf "${MAGENTA} p2     stop\n"
printf "${MAGENTA} p3     restart\n"
printf "${MAGENTA} p4     start in debug mode\n"
printf "${MAGENTA} p5     restart in debug mode\n"

printf "\n${YELLOW}     Glassfish 3.1 (required environment java 1.7)  \n\n"
printf "${MAGENTA} g1     start\n"
printf "${MAGENTA} g2     stop\n"
printf "${MAGENTA} g3     restart\n"
printf "${MAGENTA} g4     start in debug mode\n"
printf "${MAGENTA} g5     restart in debug mode\n"

printf "\n${YELLOW}     Additional Plugin  \n\n"

printf "${MAGENTA} jk     Kill All Running Java Process \n\n"
printf "${MAGENTA} jkc    Kill All Running Java Process And Clear Payara \n\n"
printf "${MAGENTA} jkcs   Kill All Running Java Process And Clear Payara And Start payara \n\n"
printf "${MAGENTA} clear_payara    Clear Payara -> Generated -> Policy, EJB Timers, JSF, XML, EJB... \n\n"

printf " \n\n ${CYAN}   please enter appropriate command (for exit CTRL+C)${NORMAL} \n\n\n"


read a   

case $a in 

p1 ) printf "\n\n ${YELLOW} Payara Starts...${NORMAL} \n\n" && /opt/payara\ 4.1.2.173/bin/./asadmin start-domain tekila ;;

p2 ) printf "\n\n ${YELLOW} Payara Stops...${NORMAL} \n\n"  && /opt/payara\ 4.1.2.173/bin/./asadmin stop-domain tekila ;;

p3 ) printf "\n\n ${YELLOW} Payara Restarts...${NORMAL} \n\n"  && /opt/payara\ 4.1.2.173/bin/./asadmin restart-domain tekila ;;

p4 ) printf "\n\n ${YELLOW} Payara Starts in debug mode...${NORMAL} \n\n"  && /opt/payara\ 4.1.2.173/bin/./asadmin start-domain --debug tekila ;;

p5 ) printf "\n\n ${YELLOW} Payara Restarts in debug mode...${NORMAL} \n\n"  && /opt/payara\ 4.1.2.173/bin/./asadmin restart-domain --debug tekila ;;

g1 ) printf "\n\n ${YELLOW} Glassfish Starts...${NORMAL} \n\n"  && /opt/gf/glassfish/bin/./asadmin start-domain tekila ;;

g2 ) printf "\n\n ${YELLOW} Glassfish Stops...${NORMAL} \n\n"  && /opt/gf/glassfish/bin/./asadmin stop-domain tekila ;;

g3 ) printf "\n\n ${YELLOW} Glassfish Restarts...${NORMAL} \n\n"  && /opt/gf/glassfish/bin/./asadmin restart-domain tekila ;;

g4 ) printf "\n\n ${YELLOW} Glassfish Starts in debug mode...${NORMAL} \n\n"  && /opt/gf/glassfish/bin/./asadmin start-domain --debug tekila ;;

g5 ) printf "\n\n ${YELLOW} Glassfish Restarts in debug mode...${NORMAL} \n\n"  && /opt/gf/glassfish/bin/./asadmin restart-domain --debug tekila ;;

jk )  printf "\n\n ${YELLOW} Java process is killing ... ${NORMAL} \n\n" &&  kill -9 `lsof -t -c  java`  &&  printf "\n\n ${GREEN} Completed successfully ${NORMAL} \n\n" ;;

jkc ) printf "\n\n ${YELLOW} Java process is killing ... ${NORMAL} \n\n" &&  kill -9 `lsof -t -c  java` && printf "\n\n ${YELLOW} Payara oldly generated ejb, policy, jsf, xml, ejb... is cleaning ... ${NORMAL} \n\n" && rm -rf /opt/payara\ 4.1.2.173/glassfish/domains/tekila/osgi-cache/felix/*  &&  rm -rf /opt/payara\ 4.1.2.173/glassfish/domains/tekila/applications/tekila-billing-gateway-ear-0.0.1  &&  rm -rf /opt/payara\ 4.1.2.173/glassfish/domains/tekila/generated/*  &&  printf "\n\n ${GREEN} Completed successfully ${NORMAL} \n\n" ;;

jkcs ) printf "\n\n ${YELLOW} Java process is killing ... ${NORMAL} \n\n" &&  kill -9 `lsof -t -c  java` && printf "\n\n ${YELLOW} Payara oldly generated ejb, policy, jsf, xml, ejb... is cleaning ... ${NORMAL} \n\n" && rm -rf /opt/payara\ 4.1.2.173/glassfish/domains/tekila/osgi-cache/felix/*  &&  rm -rf /opt/payara\ 4.1.2.173/glassfish/domains/tekila/applications/tekila-billing-gateway-ear-0.0.1  &&  rm -rf /opt/payara\ 4.1.2.173/glassfish/domains/tekila/generated/* && printf "\n\n ${YELLOW} Payara Starts...${NORMAL} \n\n" && /opt/payara\ 4.1.2.173/bin/./asadmin start-domain tekila  &&  printf "\n\n ${GREEN} Completed successfully ${NORMAL} \n\n" ;;

clear_payara )  printf "\n\n ${YELLOW} Payara oldly generated ejb, policy, jsf, xml, ejb... is cleaning ... ${NORMAL} \n\n" && rm -rf /opt/payara\ 4.1.2.173/glassfish/domains/tekila/osgi-cache/felix/*  &&  rm -rf /opt/payara\ 4.1.2.173/glassfish/domains/tekila/applications/tekila-billing-gateway-ear-0.0.1  &&  rm -rf /opt/payara\ 4.1.2.173/glassfish/domains/tekila/generated/*  &&  printf "\n\n ${GREEN} Completed successfully ${NORMAL} \n\n" ;;

* )  printf "${RED}Please  please read description ${NORMAL}";;

esac
```

Answer (score 0):

You should focus on JAVA_HOME environment variable but for safety, I will add in `/etc/systemd/system` folder `payara.service` file and set up the service as [Dennis Kriechel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45397568/2593751) do with a small change to avoid Java version problems

```
    [Unit] 
    Description=Payara Server 
    After=syslog.target network.target

    [Service] 
    Type=forking

    ExecStart =/opt/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/java -jar /opt/payara5/glassfish/lib/client/appserver-cli.jar start-domain domain_name
    ExecStop = /opt/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/java -jar /opt/payara5/glassfish/lib/client/appserver-cli.jar stop-domain domain_name
    ExecReload=/opt/jdk1.8.0_211/bin/java -jar /opt/payara5/glassfish/lib/client/appserver-cli.jar restart-domain domain_name
    [Install] 

    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

[source](https://ahmermansoor.blogspot.com/2019/05/install-payara-server-5-on-centos-7.html)